# Wasserstein distance of conditional measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, optimal-transport

Suppose I have two measures $\mu,\nu$ defined on a common measurable space. 
Let $A$ be an event in the common sigma-field. Let $\mu^A(C) = \frac{\mu(A\cap C)}{\mu(A)}$ and $\nu^A(C) = \frac{\nu(A\cap C)}{\nu(A)}$ be the corresponding conditional measures. 
Is there a way of relating the Wasserstein distance $W_p(\mu^A,\nu^A)$ to $W_p(\mu,\nu)$? 
Can we say something on the optimal coupling of $\mu^A,\nu^A$ if we know the optimal coupling of $\mu,\nu$? $W_p(\mu^A,\nu^A)$ seems to be larger, since, denoting with $\pi^*$ the optimal coupling between $\mu^A,\nu^A$:
$$ \int_\cal{X}\int_\cal{\tilde{X}} d(x,\tilde{x})d\pi^*(x,\tilde{x})= \frac{1}{\mu(A)}\int_A\int_\cal{\tilde{X}} d(x,\tilde{x})d\mu(x)\pi^*(\tilde{x}|x), $$ but I have no idea what I could say about the disintegration $\pi^*(\tilde{x}|x)$ once we take the "marginal" $d\mu^A$ out, could it compensate for the extra $\frac{1}{\mu(A)}$?

Comment: I don't see why $W_{p}(\mu^{A},\nu^{A})$ should be larger? What about $X=\tilde{X}=[0,1]$, $\mu(X)=\nu(X)=1$, $\mu(\{0\})=\mu(\{1\})=1/2$, $\nu(\{0\})=1$ and $A=\{0\}$

Comment: I am actually interested in the same question. Have you figured anything out? Theorem 4.6 and Example 4.7 in the book of Villani (OT old and new) seem very related.